# Firebase Crashlytics doesn't tracking the crash for Android after migration from fabric

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric

I am developing an android app in a company.

This app has used the Fabric library.

I can find the dependencies in the 'build.gradle' files.

And we could see the crash report in our Firebase Crashlytics console.

Recently, I changed the dependencies from the Fabric to Firebase Crashlytics.

```
// Remove the Fabric Crashlytics SDK.
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'

// Add the Firebase Crashlytics SDK.
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.1.1'
```

And I followed the migration guide documents.

Building the signing Apk success.

And I upload the APK into the PlayStore yesterday.

Today morning, when I check the Firebase Crashlytics console.

There were no crash reports related to the new version of APK.
(I couldn't find only old version's crash reports.)

But when I check it on PlayStore console, I can find some crash reports.

What should I do now?

---

When I run it on debug mode, I can find below logs.

```
2020-08-13 12:35:31.568 709-709/co.spoonme I/FirebaseCrashlytics: Initializing Crashlytics 17.1.1
```

And when I check the "Firebase > Latest Release" tab, I can find the new version.
This means that the new version is tracked by Firebase.

But only crash reports are not tracked... why......

Comment: Did you initialize firebase? like, Firebase.initialize(applicationContext) in application class

Comment: @VarunChandran, yes sure I called it!

Answer (score 0):

Firebaser here -

Make sure that you've followed all the instructions in [the migration guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=android), in case there are any old dependencies or things that you've accidentally left behind.

If you're still not able to get crash reports after [creating and forcing a test crash](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation?platform=android), try [enabling debug mode](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation?platform=android#enable_debug_logging) and forcing another test crash. After you relaunch, there should be some more logging in your logcat that tells you more about the state of Firebase initialization, and if the crash report has been successfully uploaded. If you're okay with sharing the logs, it would be a good idea to update your post with those logs for visibility.

I think it would also be helpful to see your build.gradle files and where you're initializing Firebase in your main app code.